# Project Hide of Leviathan

Tags: weapons, nanotechnology, water

Set in distant future, alright let's jump right to the question... Is it possible to apply nanotechnology to manipulate water molecules to squirt super hot streams of highly pressurized jet of water to slice through a 30mm thick titanium alloy? How will these amphorous water be remote controlled or powered? If they have the ability to multiply quickly in the ocean can we neutralize it afterward or will it cleanse humanity?

My actual design is to condense water vapour inside victim's body thereafter I'll leave some rooms for imagination. Alright I'll give humanity a fighting chance, only use pure water and sand to build your nano-tridents and don't slip up!

Water is essential for life, when there's life there will always be death... toast!

Comment: "No worry NO-man will be prosecuted!" - YES-man.

Answer (score 2):

**You have a few questions in there, but the general answer is no.**

> Is it possible to apply nanotechnology to manipulate water molecules
>   to squirt super hot streams of highly pressurized jet of water to
>   slice through a 30 mm thick titanium alloy?

You can use room temperature water and cut through [8 inches of titanium](http://www.kmtwaterjet.com/cut-titanium.aspx) with a water jet cutter pumping trillions of water molecules at 90,000psi. A single water molecule could not do this, you couldn't impart enough force on it. Also note that "super hot" for liquid water means 100°C at one atmosphere, it doesn't get hotter than that.

> How will these amorphous water be remote controlled or powered?

They/it won't be. I'm not even sure what the means, but if you're talking about controlling these water molecules then no.

> If they have the ability to multiply quickly in the ocean can we
>   neutralize it afterward or will it cleanse humanity?

They won't have that ability. If they did they would likely run out of energy before being able to kill all humans. Also, we could just defend ourselves with a towel.